# HTML td text break /new lines

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

can someone please help me with this html question?

I am parsing the data to html table cell; as I am parsing 2 variables in each cell..

I need variable values to be in new/next lines. I tried `<br>` or `'\n'` both didn't work.

```
text = arry[i].test1 + '\n '+arry[i].test2;        
$td.text( text);
```

lets say now ***test = John 12***
In Table... it should display as given image
[image]

td cell ( 2 words in separate line)

```
John
12
```

Comment: '\n' is ignored in webpage. '<br/>' may work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `$td.text(` to `$td.html(` and make sure you quote the `<br>` e.g.:

```
$td.html(temp[k].day1 + "<br>" + temp[k].day2);
```

**Explaination**

`.text()` will only change the text of the selected item, you can't insert HTML using it. `.html()` change change the HTML of an item (and therefore, by extension, also plain text).

Comment: Hi.. As I mention.. I tried <br> also.. it ddint work ....:( 


$td.text(temp[k].day1 + <br> + temp[k].day2);

Its not returning any output....

$td.text(temp[k].day1 + <\br> + temp[k].day2);

output included <\br> as string : day1<\br>day2

Comment: Try changing `$td.text(` to `$td.html(` and make sure you quote the `<br>` e.g. `$td.html(temp[k].day1 + "<br>" + temp[k].day2);`

Comment: Hi.. one last question pls... I am trying to replace td text                                    if (cell_value.indexOf("day1") > -1) {
        $(this).css({'background':'#2A2322','color':'white'})
        
I want to replace day1 to Happy1, do we have property in css to change the text? please let me know.

Comment: CSS doesn't replace text.  Ask in a new question, not in comments on this one.

Comment: I've updated my original answer to include `.html()` and an explanation on why it works. Please click the tick next to the answer to accept it if it solved your problem.